# How can I display the list of deleted words using only voice command(s)?

Tags: dragon-naturally-speaking

I wonder whether I can display the list of  deleted words using only voice command(s) in Dragon NaturallySpeaking.

[image]

I use Dragon NaturallySpeaking 12.5 professional on Windows 7 SP1 x64 Ultimate.

Comment: I haven't found any answer so far.

Comment: So I am still interested if someone has any idea.